# How to make the http interceptor spinner smart?

Tags: angularjs-directive, spinner, angular-http-interceptors

I am using http interceptor directive to load the spinner and here is my script code:

```
createProfileModule.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    var $http,
        interceptor = ['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
            var error;

            function success(response) {
                // get $http via $injector because of circular dependency problem
                $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
                if($http.pendingRequests.length < 1) {
                    $('#loadingWidget').hide();
                }
                return response;
            }

            function error(response) {
                // get $http via $injector because of circular dependency problem
                $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
                if($http.pendingRequests.length < 1) {
                    $('#loadingWidget').hide();
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }

            return function (promise) {

                $('#loadingWidget').show();
                return promise.then(success, error);
            }
        }];

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
}]);
```

and in HTML i am calling the div like this with the required CSS

```
<div id="loadingWidget" style="display:none;"></div>


 <style>
#loadingWidget { position: absolute; z-index:2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000000 url(/ERegII-1.0/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center; 
    cursor: not-allowed;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
     content:'Loading..';
     background-size:100px 100px;

     }
</style>
```

What I want to make this spinner smart. I don't want to display the spinner on every small http call. So if my request if really small and it takes some milliseconds, I don't want to display the spinner. I want to add a delay time to the spinner.. let say 2 second. So if the request it taking more than 2 second this spinner should show up otherwise I don't want to display it.
Can someone help me to find the solution for this?
I have tried https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker but seems like doesn't work for me.

Can someone help me to make it smarter please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $timeout service (or native setTimeout) to delay showing the loader if the request is taking longer than 2 seconds. Here is an example with $timeout..

```
createProfileModule.config(['$httpProvider', '$timeout', function ($httpProvider, $timeout) {
...
var finished = true;

return function (promise) {
    finished = false;
    $timeout(function () {
        if (!finished) $('#loadingWidget').show();
    }, 2000); // wait 2 seconds
    return promise.then(success, error).finally(function () {
        finished = true;
    });
}
```

I'm using a local variable called 'finished' to keep track of whether the request is complete yet. We set it to false before each request and in the 'finally' callback of the promise we set it to true to signify that the request is finished. Then, you simply delay the showing of the loader 2 seconds using $timeout and only show it if finished is still false